# Buscar informações em mais de uma tabela

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5, expressões-lambda

Em meu projeto atualmente tenho 3 tabelas: Alunos, Ocorrências e Usuários. Nelas tenho as *views* e os *controllers*.

Até ai, tudo bem. Meus relacionamentos são: Alunos&Ocorrencias(1,N) / Ocorrencias&Usuarios(N,1).

O meu problema é que na *action* Details, tanto de Ocorrências quanto na de Usuários, eu não consigo mostrar algumas informações de relacionamentos. Na de ocorrências não consigo mostrar o nome do aluno e nem do usuário(mas na Index, eu consigo mostrar esses nomes), e na de usuários não consigo mostrar o nome do aluno(que teria que ser mostrado pelo fato de vir do relacionamento de Alunos&Ocorrencias).

Aqui meu código que está na *action* que mostra todas as informações, menos essas mencionadas anteriormente:

## *ActionResult* do *Controller* Ocorrencias

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Ocorrencia ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias.Find(id);

        if (ocorrencia == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

## *ActionResult* do *Controller* Usuarios

```
    public ActionResult Detalhes(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
        Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Include(o => o.Ocorrencias).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioID == id);

        if (usuario == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar ? Isso é o caso de um join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não** use `Find`. `Find` traz apenas o registro solicitado, sem os relacionamentos entre as demais entidades.

Mude para `FirstOrDefault`, e use `Include` para carregar os dados relacionados:

```
var ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencias
                 .Include(o => o.Aluno)
                 .Include(o => o.Usuario)
                 .FirstOrDefault(o => o.OcorrenciaID == id);
```

No caso do `Usuario`, não precisa usar `AsNoTracking()`. O resto está correto:

```
var usuario = db.Usuarios.Include(o => o.Ocorrencias).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UsuarioID == id);
```

Não esqueça de incluir o `using System.Data.Entity;` no cabeçalho dos `Controllers`.

Comment: Cigano, no caso das ocorrências funcionou numa boa, mas no caso do usuário não funcionou. Só pra deixar mais claro, o aluno só se relaciona com a ocorrência e a ocorrência se relaciona tanto com aluno quanto com usuários. Então, como posso pegar o nome do aluno que ta na ocorrência e mostrar ele quando buscar os detalhes do usuário ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Pela ocorrência seria `@ocorrencia.Usuario.Nome`.

Comment: Dessa forma eu sei cigano. Mas como o nome do aluno e mostro na tabela de usuarios ? Acho que fui mais claro.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Na verdade não foi muito claro, mas acho que eu entendi. Se você quer carregar o nome do aluno a partir da ocorrência, é `@ocorrencia.Aluno.Nome`.

Comment: Ok. O que ta acontecendo é que quando detalho as ocorrências relacionadas a um login o nome do aluno não é mostrado. E eu queria mostrar o nome do aluno na view de detalhes do usuário. Porque quero mostrar pro meu usuário as ocorrências que ele gerou e pra quem, entendeu ? É isso que ta acontecendo.

Comment: Aí você usa `db.Usuarios.Include(u => u.Ocorrencias.Select(o => o.Aluno))`.

Comment: Muito bom Cigano, funcionou aqui ! Valeu demais !